# Showing particular row data as column

Tags: sql, mariadb

My table is as follows:

| Date | Code | Price | MA5 | MA20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | APPLE | 1000 | 1080 | 1090 |
| 2022-01-02 | APPLE | 1100 | 1084 | 1100 |
| 2022-01-03 | APPLE | 1200 | 1090 | 1100 |
| 2022-01-01 | MICROSOFT | 7 | 9 | 10 |
| 2022-01-02 | MICROSOFT | 7.5 | 8 | 9.5 |
| 2022-01-03 | MICROSOFT | 8 | 8.5 | 9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 | NASDAQ | 14400 | 15600 | 16700 |
| 2022-01-02 | NASDAQ | 14500 | 15200 | 16100 |
| 2022-01-03 | NASDAQ | 14600 | 15000 | 16000 |

I'm currently saving NASDAQ values and stock data on the same table using MariaDB.

However, I want to show NASDAQ's MA values as new column fields into rest of the field, as NASDAQ_MA5, NASDAQ_MA20.

My question is, how do I select nasdaq's MA5 and MA20 values and put it as the values according to the matching dates? My desired output is as follows:

| Date | Code | Price | MA5 | MA20 | NASDAQ_MA5 | NASDAQ_MA20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | APPLE | 1000 | 1080 | 1090 | 15600 | 16700 |
| 2022-01-02 | APPLE | 1100 | 1084 | 1100 | 15200 | 16100 |
| 2022-01-03 | APPLE | 1200 | 1090 | 1100 | 15000 | 16000 |
| 2022-01-01 | MICROSOFT | 7 | 9 | 10 | 15600 | 16700 |
| 2022-01-02 | MICROSOFT | 7.5 | 8 | 9.5 | 15200 | 16100 |
| 2022-01-03 | MICROSOFT | 8 | 8.5 | 9 | 15000 | 16000 |

I've been trying the following:

```
        SELECT *, 
        (PARTITION BY DATE, case when (code='NASDAQ') then MA5 else NULL end) as 'NASDAQ_MA5',
        (PARTITION BY DATE, case when (code='NASDAQ') then MA20 else NULL end) as 'NASDAQ_MA20'
        FROM TABLE
```

Your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: "*I'm currently saving NASDAQ rows at the very end of the table*" - no, you are not. Rows in a relational database have no implied sort order. There is no such thing as "the end of the table"

Comment: I've updated my desired output. What i meant by saving rows at the very end of the table was to show how i'm using a single table to save both stock data and NASDAQ data. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sure theres a more efficient way of doing this, but heres a way to solve your issue using 2 subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.*, (SELECT t2.MA5
              FROM tableA t2
              WHERE t1.date = t2.date
              AND code = 'NASDAQ') as NASDAQ_MA5,
              (SELECT t2.MA20
              FROM tableA t2
              WHERE t1.date = t2.date
              AND code = 'NASDAQ') as NASDAQ_MA20
FROM tableA t1
WHERE code != 'NASDAQ'
```

Try it out [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e292ec89510a9a369f28e534a9ca8102).

Comment: Weird you have chosen to go with this implementation, out of the answers posted it is the most poorly performing, it unecessarily reads the table *3 times* and each subquery will require aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the two distinct sets of data. It probably makes sense to define a CTE to keep the definitions clear, then join with your main table - either an *inner join* if there's always a corresponding date or *left join* if there might not be.

This *assumes* there's only a single nasdaq code for each date, if that's not the case you can aggregate in the CTE as required.

```
with nasdaq as (
    select date, MA5 NASDAQ_MA5, MA20 NASDAQ_MA20
    from t
    where code = 'NASDAQ'
)
select t.*, n.NASDAQ_MA5, n.NASDAQ_MA20
from t
left join nasdaq n on n.date=t.date
where t.code != 'NASDAQ';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self join on date column and separating the data by CODE = 'NASDAQ'. Here is a way of doing this:

```
select a.*, b.ma5 as NASDAQ_MA5, b.ma20 as NASDAQ_MA20 from table1 a
left outer join (select date, ma5,ma20 from table1 where code = 'NASDAQ') b
on a.date = b.date where a.code <> 'NASDAQ'
```

Comment: This answer is essentially the same as that by @Stu but does not have any explanation. Please avoid code anly answers in the future, though it may help OP who can verify them in their projects they are less helpful to the community who may wish to refer to your insights.